# Python - Ciclo seno em graus

Tags: python, lista, while

Boas em pretendo calcular o ciclo seno (sin) em graus entre 0 e 390 com um intervalo de 10.

```
print('Ciclo seno em graus entre 0 e 390 com intervalo de 10')
a=0
while True:
    if 0<=a<=390:
        math.sin(math.degrees(a))
        a=a+10
    else:
        break
    print(a)
```

não estou a conseguir obter o resultado correcto...

Comment: obrigado pelo comentário, no entanto estão a aparecer valores acima de 390 e não usei o seno... acho o resultado mais correto complementando a sua resposta seria: ```for a in range(0,391,10): print(math.degrees(math.sin(a)))```

Comment: Desculpe, falha minha: `for a in range(0,391,10): print(math.sin(math.degrees(a)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para começar, as funções circulares - [seno, cosseno e tangente](https://matematicabasica.net/funcoes-trigonometricas/#:%7E:text=A%20fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20seno%20%C3%A9%20uma,x%20%C3%A9%20um%20n%C3%BAmero%20real.) - são obtidas através do círculo trigonométrico. Este, por sua vez, vai de **0 a 360°**. Por isso, não faz sentido em tabelar os senos no intervalo **0 a 390°**, uma vez que os valores de 360° a 390° são iguais às do intervalo de **0 a 30°**.

Outra coisa, os valores dos senos compreendidos no intervalo **[1, 179]**, possuem sinal **POSITIVO**. Os senos correspondentes a **0** e **180°** possuem valor **NULO** e os senos compreendidos no intervalo **[181, 359]**, possuem sinal **NEGATIVO**.

Além disso, o cálculo do seno é sempre baseado em radianos.

Levando em consideração todas estas observações, podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
from math import sin, radians

print('Ciclo do seno de "0" à "360°" com intervalo de "10°"')
for i in range(0, 361, 10):
    if 0 <= i < 360:
        print(f'{f"{i:<4} = "}{sin(radians(i)):.4f}')
    else:
        print(f'{f"{i:<4} = 0.0000"}')
```

Observe que o bloco **for** percorre o **range(0, 361, 10)**, isto é, percorre o intervalo de **0** a **361° - 1**, ou seja, o intervalo **0** a **360°**, saltando de 10 em 10°.

Observe que a variável temporária do bloco **for**, ou seja, a variável **i**, corresponde ao valor em **graus**. E, portanto, não preciso converter tau valor novamente em graus - aplicando a função **degrees()**.

Finalmente podemos calcular o seno e exibir o resultado com **4** casas decimais.

Comment: Mas e se ele quiser dar uma volta completa **e** os 30 graus que faltam?

Comment: @Luiz Felipe, boa noite. Uma volta completa é de `0 à 360`. Duas voltas completas é de `0 à 720`. De `0 à 390` seria uma volta completa + 30°.

Comment: Sim, eu sei! E foi o que disse no meu comentário acima. O problema é que, ao limitar a 360 graus, você está “ignorando” os 30 graus que faltam para os 390 que o AP pediu, não? De todo modo, deixei o meu +1 porque achei a sua solução bem elegante.

Comment: @Luiz Felipe, entendi completamente sua colocação, só que como expliquei no primeiro parágrafo do meu post não há razões para RECALCULAR um valor que já havíamos calculado anteriormente. Forte braço!

Comment: Bom dia, muito obrigado pelo comentário compreendi muito bem a explicação só fiquei com uma questão: para que serve o  `sep='\t'`? é que já experimentei retirá-lo do código, mas não alterou nada.

Comment: Para completar o seu comentário visto que no meu problema pedia em graus deverá alterar esta parte do código `print(f'{i}° = {math.degrees(sin(radians(i))):.4f}', sep='\t')` para converter o radiano em graus.

Comment: Estive agora a verificar os cálculos na calculadora e acabei por ficar um pouco confuso... Por exemplo sen(90) em graus dá 1 e o sen^-1(1) é 90. Porém aqui no python pelos vistos a função sen é em radianos ou seja sen(90) em radianos dá 0,894 e sen^-1(0,894) dá 1,106. Portanto no programa sen(90) radianos é 0.894 e convertendo depois para graus usando `math.degrees` é a mesma coisa que sin^-1(0,894) graus que é 63,38?

Comment: @Diogo, o `\t` serve apenas para separar as saídas com uma tabulação - três espaços. Como as saídas foram formatadas com `f-string` de fato, não faz diferença. Por isso vou remove-la do código. Isso foi uma desatenção minha. Obrigado pela observação.

Answer (score 4):

Não sei bem o que você quer com esse código, já que não mostra o valor calculado do seno.
De qualquer forma, basta mudar a posição do print para que o range de a seja mostrado corretamente:

```
    print('Ciclo seno em graus entre 0 e 390 com intervalo de 10')
    a=0
    while True:    
           if 0<=a<=390:
               print(a)
               print(math.sin(math.degrees(a)))
               a=a+10
           else:
               break
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o `while` e o `if` deveriam ser:

```
while a <= 390:
    if 0 >= a <= 390:
        math.sin(math.degrees(a))
        a = a + 10
    else:
        break
    print(a)
```

Por que o `while True` deve estar impossibilitando de sair do *loop*.